# How can I speed up the passing of objects between two sockets using an ObjectOutputStream and the writeObject() and reset() methods?

Tags: java, performance, sockets, objectoutputstream

I am writing an application (a multiplayer game) where objects need to be passed from one instance of the application to another (and very quickly) via a server.

I am using `ObjectOutputStreams` and `ObjectInputStreams` obtained through the sockets to do this.

However, the state of the objects being passed is constantly being updated, meaning the typical `writeObject()` method won't do the trick (it only writes the object once, then passes a reference to it subsequent times it is called, meaning the values of its instance variables are never actually updated).

To "fix" this I have been calling the `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` method after every call to `writeObject()`, which does solve the problem of updating the object state; however, it runs much too slow, which I assume is a result of the objects being passed in their entirety each "refresh".

My question then is, how do I update the state of the object I am passing over the network without having to entirely rewrite the object? (I'm assuming this is how I would speed things up; if I'm wrong, or if other methods exist, please share) Thank you in advance for any advice!

Also, regarding the size of the object being passed: it isn't overly large... A couple of boolean variables, a couple of double arrays, and some other minor variables (No lists of length 1000 each containing another list).

Comment: Consider using paragraphs and code notation on your next questions/answers. `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a `BufferedOutputStream` between the `ObjectOutputStream` and the socket.
2. Use a `BufferedInputStream` between the `ObjectInputStream` and the socket.
3. Call `flush()` after every `writeObject()` or `writeUnshared().`

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll get around to testing it shortly and let you know if it solves my problem.